# MongoDB - RestAPI- ExpressJS - Put Method does not appear to be working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm attempting to build my first REST API using MongoDB and Node.

I'm using Postman to test the API.

all of the methods appear to be working, but I currently cannot update any "articles" in my database, using the post method.

I'm essentially trying to edit the "title" and "content" of the articles, but Postman is returning ("update not successful").

```
//jshint esversion:6


const express = require("express");  //creating four constant, and requiring the modules
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({  //parse requests
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));    //public directory to store static files

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });    // connect to local database

const articleSchema = {    //created article schema
  title: String,
  content: String
};


const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);   //created article model

//Requests Targetting all Articles

app.route("/articles")

  .get(function (req, res) {
    Article.find(function (err, foundArticles) {      //search through articles and send to client
      if (!err) {
        res.send(foundArticles);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }

    });
  })

  .post(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.title);
    console.log(req.body.content);

    const newArticle = new Article({
      title: (req.body.title),
      content: (req.body.content)
    });
    newArticle.save(function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Successfully added a new article");
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }

    });
  })

  .delete(function (req, res) {
    Article.deleteMany(function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Succesfully deleted all articles.");
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
    });
  });


///request targeting a specific article/////////////////


app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")   // match request parameters

  .get(function (req, res) {
    Article.findOne({ title: req.params.articleTitle },
      function (err, foundArticle) {
        if (foundArticle) {
          res.send(foundArticle);
        } else {
          res.send("No articles matching that title was found");
        }
      });
  })

  .put(function (req, res) {

    Article.updateMany(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
      { overwrite: true },
      function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("success")
          res.send("successfully updated article")
        } else {
          res.send("update not successful");
          console.log("error")
        }
      }
    );
  });


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");  //listen on port
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `app.use(bodyParser());` to your code, like this:

   ```
   app.use(bodyParser());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
   ```
2. You are supposed to use the `update` method instead of the `updateMany` method, as you are updating a single entry in the database.

**For information:** The body parser you are using is deprecated. If you are using Express >= 4.16.0, then you can use this: `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` by replacing your body parser code with this:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Hope everything works now.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately I'm still having the same result. If there is any update I will let you know.